# IE8 and trusted sites

Tags: security, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to tell IE8 to trust all sites by default ? I know that could be a security issue but browsing is controlled by the (transparent) proxy anyway.

So users cannot use a site or part of it until they put the site in the trusted list and for not so experienced users that is an issue.

**Update**

Normal public web sites are not the problem. The problems begin on web "applications": bank, webmail, tax authority. Not all, but some and after putting them into trusted sites it is working.

Comment: What is your OS? The distribuitons of IE8 are slightly different if you are on XP, Vista/7, or a Server OS

Answer (score 1):

You can't put all sites in the Trusted Zone, but you can make the Internet Zone's security settings the same as the Trusted Zone, which would have the same effect.

This would be a staggeringly bad idea. The Trusted Zone settings allow sites to pretty much own your machine.

I think you have a different problem:

> So users cannot use a site or part of it until they put the site in the trusted list

That should certainly not be the case. Even with the highest security settings you can still see web sites, and the default settings for the Internet Zone are quite sufficient to browse pretty much any public web site. If your machines can't view sites in the Internet Zone there would seem to be something wrong with them.

Comment: Yes, they can see but they cannot use because of embeeded JavaScript, Java Applets, etc that don't run due to security settings and gives no hint/log/trace where fails.

Comment: The default Internet Zone settings allow JavaScript, Flash etc. to run.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible as IE8 claims to be the most secure browser in the world, so they would hardly add "allow all sites with viruses etc"